# matlab program help

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Wanting to write a matlab program to solve the following iteration: 
$x^{(k+1)}=b+\alpha\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}x^k,k=0,1,2,\cdots$
where alpha is a real constant. Find the values of alpha for which the method converges. Show the first two iterations for any of this choice of alpha.

I am completely lost.

edit: 
no need for a program...
Here is what I have so far. Eigenvalues are 1,3 for the matrix. I took $|\alpha*eigenvalues|>1$  Thus giving me that $(-1/3)<\alpha<1/3$ and $-1<\alpha<1$
I am assuming that I can leave b in the first two iterations, but how would I represent $\alpha$?
thanks for any help.

Comment: It is hard to read your formula.

Comment: I think the formula that he write is somethin like $x^{(k+1)}=b+\alpha\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}x^k$

Comment: Correct. I couldn't find a way to input that.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started:

`A = [2, 1; 1, 2];
x = [1; 0]; % put x(0) here
b = [1; 0]; % put b here
alpha = 0.01; % put alpha here
num_iter = 100 % the total number of iterations
for k = 1:num_iter
    x = b + alpha*A*x; % remove the ";" to see result at each step
end
x % print final result`

More hints:

- $x^{(k+1)} = \alpha^k A^k x^0 + \sum_{n = 0}^{k-1} \alpha^n A^n b $, so you're going to have a problem if $\alpha^kA^k$ has really large entries.
- What are the eigenvalues of $A$?
- Consider $A = P^{-1}DP$. Then $A^k = P^{-1}D^kP$, so $\alpha^kA^k = P^{-1}(\alpha D)^kP$

Comment: I understand what you have written but I am looking for alpha and I don't know what b or x(0) are.

Comment: Ok, then you will have to show that the convergence depends only on $\alpha$, and not on $x(0)$ or $b$. Use the program (with different values of those three parameters) to explore the situation. I'll give you a couple more hints above.